# How to implement camera exposure control in a UIImagePicker based app?

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, avfoundation

I have a UIImagePicker based app that controls the camera with custom overlays to handle a heads up display as well as digital zooming.

I would like to add "touch to adjust exposure" like the normal iPhone camera app has.  When you zoom in, you ultimately want to change exposure based on something other than "the big picture view".

UIImagePicker seems to have no tools for doing this... it's all automatic.  If I use my custom overlay, the touch events are disregarded by the UIImagePicker.

I've attempted to subclass the UIImagePicker and pass my touch events to Super after they come along... no luck.

I'm currently looking at the AVFoundation framework as it's AVCaptureSession supports setting exposure based on a point.  I could toss my existing code and replace it with these tools, but before I do that I thought I'd ask if I was missing a simpler option.

Yes, I know about the WWDC's tutorials on AVFoundation.  I'll go that route if tweaking UIImagePicker is out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 4.3, Apple is now passing touch events along to the appropriate camera controllers.
The result is that exposure and focus controls now respond to touch events on your custom overlay.  This is fantastic; thank you Apple.  Interestingly, I can find no reference to this new functionality in any of the release notes or documentation.

Answer (score 0):

UIImagePickerController doesn't provide exposure control. You need to use AVFoundation.